# Analysing a Java Gradle project on SonarQube.com with Travis CI

Tags: java, gradle, sonarqube, travis-ci, sonarqube-scan

I have a Java Gradle projet hosted on GitHub and connected to travis CI.

On the root of this project, I have:

**.travis.yml**

```
language: java

addons:
  sonarqube: true
env:
  global:
    - secure: <the token generated on sonarqube.com>
script:
  gradle check
```

**.sonarsource.properties**

```
wallboard.teamAtSonarSource=support
sonar.host.url=http://sonarqube.com
```

**build.gradle**

```
// Uses DSL plugins resolution introduced in Gradle 2.1
plugins {
  id "java"
  id "jacoco"
  id "org.sonarqube" version "1.2"
}

sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.projectName", "Java :: Simple Project :: SonarQube Scanner for Gradle"
        property "sonar.projectKey", "org.sonarqube:java-gradle-simple"
        property "sonar.jacoco.reportPath", "${project.buildDir}/jacoco/test.exec"
    }
}

allprojects {
  ext.baseVersion = "0.1"
  ext.snapshotVersion = true

  group = "org.sonarqube"
  version = "$baseVersion" + (snapshotVersion ? "-SNAPSHOT" : "")
}

test {
  ignoreFailures = true
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

repositories {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/"
    }
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
  }
}
```

I found this one on [SonarSource example repo](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/languages/java/gradle/java-gradle-simple)

The travis CI pass but the sonarqube.com analysis do not run. I am new to Travis, SonarQube and Gradle, so I don't know where exactly I am wrong.

Edit: Here is the [Travis logs](https://s3.amazonaws.com/archive.travis-ci.org/jobs/162143873/log.txt).

Comment: Can you give the link to the Travis logs? It's not possible to help without execution logs.

Comment: And just FYI, here's the Travis YML of a project that successfully analyses his code using Gradle: https://github.com/andstatus/andstatus/blob/master/.travis.yml#L72

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarSourceTeam I added the logs my question.

Answer (score 1):

SonarQube analysis is not executed. You have to call it explicitly. Something like:

```
gradle sonarqube
```

Please read the documentation for the [SonarQube Scanner for Gradle](http://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/gradle.html).

Comment: Thank you. I changed my travis file to execute `gradle sonarqube`, following your examples, but it's not better. Can someone fast check [my test project](https://github.com/roipoussiere/java-gradle-travis-sonar-test) (new logs [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/archive.travis-ci.org/jobs/162227441/log.txt))?

Answer (score 1):

First, you should create a token at sonarqube.com. It is under My Account > security.

Then you need to add the token to your sonar properties as

```
sonar.login=XXX
```

You may also need to change the url to https.

One thing to note is the token is unsecure. To secure the token follow [this guide](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Encrypting-environment-variables). You will have to pass the token as a variable to gradle. I believe you can do this with `-Psonar.login=$SONAR_TOKEN`.